# Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have a doubt regarding of the way I proved something and I am not sure it is good.

Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\Bbb C$ (the complex field).

Let $y \in V$ and let $x = \lambda y$, where $\lambda$ is a real number.

Then I have to prove that:
$$|(x,y)|= \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}\sqrt{\langle y,y\rangle}.$$

I know that (according to the inner product axioms):
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}\sqrt{\langle y,y\rangle}&=\sqrt{\langle\lambda y,\lambda y\rangle}\sqrt{\langle y,y\rangle} \\
&= \sqrt{\lambda \langle y,\lambda y\rangle}\sqrt{\langle y,y\rangle} \\ 
&= \sqrt{\lambda^2 \langle y, y\rangle}\sqrt{\langle y,y\rangle} \\
&= \sqrt{( \lambda \langle y, y\rangle)^2} \\
&= |\lambda|\langle y, y\rangle \quad \text{and because of the positive axiom we get that} \\
&= |\lambda ( y, y)|= |(x, y)|
\end{align}$$

and that is it.

But then I thought to myself that
$$\lambda\langle y, y\rangle= \sqrt{( \lambda \langle y, y\rangle)^2}= |\lambda|\langle y, y\rangle,$$
and if $ \lambda <0$ we get that 
$y=0$, which clearly is not the only case

So where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computations are correct;  I think there is an inconsistency in

$$\lambda \langle y,y\rangle=\sqrt{(\lambda\langle y,y\rangle)^2}=|\lambda|\langle y,y\rangle, $$

however. The first equality should be $|\lambda|\langle y,y\rangle=\sqrt{(\lambda\langle y,y\rangle)^2},$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb R$.

In particular, if $\lambda<0$, then $-\lambda\langle y,y\rangle=\sqrt{(\lambda\langle y,y\rangle)^2}.$

Question: why don't you choose $\lambda\in \mathbb C$?

**Edit**

If $\lambda\in \mathbb C$ , then $\langle\lambda y,y\rangle=\lambda\langle y,y\rangle$ , while $\langle y,\lambda y\rangle=\bar{\lambda} \langle y,y\rangle $,  or viceversa, according to conventions (if $\lambda$ is real you return to the formulae above, as $\lambda=\bar{\lambda}$). In other words

$$(\langle \lambda y,y\rangle)(\langle y,\lambda y\rangle)=|\lambda|^2 (\langle y,y\rangle)^2.$$

*Mutatis mutandis,* all is used is that  vector spaces over $\mathbb C$ are endowed with sesquilinear inner products, not bilinear ones.

Comment: Is it true even if $ \lambda \in C$ ?

Comment: If $\lambda\in\mathbb C$, then $\langle \lambda y,y\rangle=\lambda\langle y,y\rangle$, while $\langle y,\lambda y\rangle=\bar{\lambda}\langle y,y\rangle,$ or viceversa, according to conventions. In other words  $(\langle \lambda y,y\rangle)(\langle y, \lambda y\rangle)=|\lambda|^2(\langle y,y\rangle)^2$.

Comment: I edit it into my answer, for completeness.